# Kendowindow with Extended desktop configuration

Tags: kendo-ui, drag-and-drop, window

When I create a KendoWindow on Dual Monitor system, configured as extended desktop, Dragging the windo to the second window hides the KendoWindow.

I have tried Chrome and IE10

The effect can be seen with Kendo demo site.
http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/window/index

A popup via window.open would allow me to open on current monitor and drag to extended, so why not KendoWindow?

Answer (score 0):

Is your browser window in the extended desktop as well? If not then Kendo UI (and any other HTML element) will not leave the browser window and go to the extended desktop. HTML elements can only render in browser window which hosts the DOM tree.

A `window.open` works because it creates a separate browser window which is a native to the OS and can be dragged around desktop.s

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, that is what I thought.
I have implemented via window.open, and share the datasource between windows via localstorage, as per link below. It works but feels a bit clunky. 
http://www.telerik.com/forums/how-to-save-and-retrieve-data-from-kendoui-datasource-in-local-storage-of-html5